# Unity3d c# TCP client code can't receive second message in a row

Tags: unity-game-engine, tcpclient, tcpserver, tcpsocket

I have similar problem maybe the same like [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/241384/why-i-cant-receive-2-messages-in-a-row-from-my-ser.html).

From the server (Java TCP Server) im doing this:

```
public void sendMsg(String msg) {

    out.println(msg); // msg is: "MSG Hello" without quetes

    out.flush();

}
```

when i push it twice or more i receive only first message in client code which is unity3d code c# socket

```
void Update() {

    if(connected) {

        try {

            if(theStream.DataAvailable) {

                String data = sr.ReadLine();
// bla bla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `if(theStream.DataAvailable)`. You cannot check if data is available that way since if you have already received it, it is not available. While the `ReadLine` function only returns one line to you, it may read much more than one line.

So here's what happens:

1. All data is sent.
2. Data is available, you call `ReadLine`. It reads all the data and returns one line to you.
3. No data is available now, since it has already been read from the connection.

There are other problems with that check too. If it's trying to avoid calling `ReadLine` if a line isn't available, it won't do that. Some data being available doesn't mean a whole line is. (Imagine if the other end maliciously sends just a single `X` byte.)

Comment: how can i check if there is data and receive that when it is full message? also multiple messages in a row?

Comment: i just remove the check "if(theStream.DataAvailable) {}" but when i run the unity client the app frezee until i kill the server... i'm trying this "String data = sr.ReadLine(); print(data);" in the update() method

Comment: I would recommend using a thread to wait for the data. That's the easiest way. Other ways are more complex -- you'll have to do the line processing yourself, saving leftovers, and so on.

Comment: do you have any example about that? how i can create a thread and wait for a message from the server.

Comment: [Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).